# Celery IOError: Socket closed

Tags: python, sockets, flask, celery

I'm getting this error randomly: `IOError: Socket closed`. It sounds like the web request is taking too long (with the Celery task?) and terminating before the response is finished, hence the socket closed. But if I call the task synchronously, instead of using `.delay()`, I don't have this problem.

I'm using CloudAMQP as the broker and Redis as the result store. Everything works flawless in testing and on dev servers (dev and production both use Heroku).

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://urlhere'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://urlhere'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
```

Celery task:

```
@celery.task()
def _track(model_type, recipient_id, event_name, properties=None):
    '''Tracks an event for a recipient'''
    properties = properties or {}
    super_properties = _get_super_properties(recipient)
    people_properties = _get_people_properties(recipient)

    all_properties = dict(super_properties)
    all_properties.update(properties)

    member = _get_member(recipient_id)

    try:
        # track
        mp.track(member.id, event_name, all_properties)
    except Exception, e:
        email_body = unicode(e)    
        mailer.notify_dev('Mixpanel error', email_body)
```

Trace:

```
 File "/app/app/helpers/tracker.py", line 165, in track
   _track.delay(model_type, recipient.id, event_name, properties)
 File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 453, in delay
   return self.apply_async(args, kwargs)
 File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 559, in apply_async
   **dict(self._get_exec_options(), **options)
 File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/base.py", line 353, in send_task
   reply_to=reply_to or self.oid, **options
 File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/amqp.py", line 305, in publish_task
   **kwargs
 File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 172, in publish
   routing_key, mandatory, immediate, exchange, declare)
 File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 457, in _ensured
   interval_max)
 File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 369, in ensure_connection
   interval_start, interval_step, interval_max, callback)
 File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/utils/__init__.py", line 243, in retry_over_time
   return fun(*args, **kwargs)
 File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 237, in connect
   return self.connection
 File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 741, in connection
   self._connection = self._establish_connection()
 File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 696, in _establish_connection
   conn = self.transport.establish_connection()
 File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/transport/pyamqp.py", line 116, in establish_connection
   conn = self.Connection(**opts)
 File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/amqp/connection.py", line 183, in __init__
   return self._x_open(virtual_host)
 File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/amqp/connection.py", line 627, in _x_open
   (10, 41),    # Connection.open_ok
 File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/amqp/abstract_channel.py", line 67, in wait
   self.channel_id, allowed_methods)
 File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/amqp/connection.py", line 240, in _wait_method
   self.method_reader.read_method()
 File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/amqp/method_framing.py", line 189, in read_method
   raise m
IOError: Socket closed
```

Comment: can you show a snippet of the code that is causing this problem. you are connecting to rabbitmq, right? are you sure that it is configured correctly ?

Comment: @scytale The code should be fine. It's a basic task making a call to Mixpanel. It works fine in testing, but randomly produces this socket error in production. I am using CloudAMQP, so there's no configuration. The queue itself functions correctly. The trace does look like there's a problem with the connection, but it's not consistent.

Comment: @scytale BTW this is all with Celery. I do not use AMQP directly, it's celery that uses it.

Comment: yes I understand that you're connecting to rabbitmq via celery. There clearly is a problem with the connection, but you'll need to give more information for anyone to be able to help you. For one thing you should update your question to mention that you're using CloudAMQP, you should also show your celeryconfig.py

Comment: @scytale Updated with that info. I'm using a very basic Celery setup that works fine in development.

Comment: anything in the CloudAMQP RabbitMQ log stream at the relevant times?

Comment: @scytale Unfortunately, log streams are only available for dedicated $100+ plans. My guess was that it has something to do with the max connections. My plan has 20 max connections, and I am noticing that as more requests come in executing more tasks, the open connections is going up (it even goes up to 22 out of 20, but I haven't been able to simulate the IOError).

Comment: without server-side logging you're going to find it hard to establish what is going on. you could try capturing traffic to the rabbitmq server and then using e.g. Wireshark to see what is going on at a network level - at least that way if your connections are getting dropped by the other side you should be able to see it.